# Shopify shipping notification based on variant inventory

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to show a shipping message to users based on variant inventory, then pass it through as a line item. Currently everything is working, you just have to click onto another variant. However it does not show up when the page is loaded. How can I make the shipping notification show when the page loads on the first variant? I am using the Debut theme which does not have selectCallback.

```
$stockMessage = $('#stockMessage');
      $stockMessageInStock = $('#stockMessageInStock');
      $stockMessageMadeToOrder = $('#stockMessageMadeToOrder');
      $stockMessagePreOrder = $('#stockMessagePreOrder');
  if (invQty > 0 ) {
      $stockMessage.hide();
      $stockMessageMadeToOrder.hide();
      $stockMessagePreOrder.hide();
      $stockMessageInStock.show();
      $('#stock-status-prop').val('In stock - ships in 1-3 days');
    } else if (invQty > -19) {
      $stockMessage.show();
      $stockMessageMadeToOrder.show();
      $stockMessagePreOrder.hide();
      $stockMessageInStock.hide();
      $('#stock-status-prop').val('In production - ships in 1-3 weeks');
   } else {
      $stockMessage.hide();
      $stockMessageMadeToOrder.hide();
      $stockMessagePreOrder.show();
      $stockMessageInStock.hide();
      $('#stock-status-prop').val('Pre order');
   };
```

You can see my js here:

http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0597/3409/t/56/assets/theme.js?6194985269805756198

Live site:

https://roughandtumbledesign.com/collections/convertible-backpacks/products/new-generation-hobo-pack-adjustable

Thanks!!